# MySQL Many-to-many relation - Change OR SELECT into AND

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following code

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t.`id_task` FROM crm_task t LEFT JOIN crm_task_tagtogroup asso USING (`id_task`) WHERE asso.id_tag IN(1,2,5,6)
```

My problem is that it *includes* on `OR` basis not `AND` basis (Excldude works fine). Lookin for efficent way to change `id_task IN ()` to `AND`.
So i recieve all entries that have 1,2,5 and 6 tag assigned

Database Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `crm_task_tagtogroup` (
`id_task`  INT UNSIGNED  , 
`id_tag`  INT UNSIGNED  , 
 UNIQUE KEY (`id_task`, `id_tag`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

CREATE TABLE `crm_task` (
`id_task`  INT UNSIGNED   AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
`name`  VARCHAR(30), 
`description`  TEXT , 
`priority`  INT UNSIGNED  , 
`client_id`  INT UNSIGNED  , 
`value_netto`  INT UNSIGNED
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
```

Any Ideas? Would like to keep it simple and not include foreach checking in PHP script

Comment: Wonder what this downvote is for...

Comment: Perhaps missing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Are you looking for a php or sql answer?

Comment: Updated question to simplify i need SQL

Comment: Great! Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. If you want LEFT JOIN result, move the WHERE clause condition to the ON clause. (Or do INNER JOIN, if you want INNER JOIN result.)

Comment: However, LEFT JOIN makes no sense here, since you don't select any outer table columns.

Comment: It's for filtering only. I have tasks with assigned tags. Want to filter tasks that have assigned tag 'Todo' and 'important'. Currently getting tasks that have "important" OR "todo" tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you are looking to get is close to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.`id_task` FROM crm_task t INNER JOIN crm_task_tagtogroup tag ON (id_tag in (1,2,3)) having count(distinct id_tag) = 3;
```

place your list of parameters within the on clause and the count of these parameters at the end of the having count statement.

This will mean that only results that match the number of parameters are returned.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Good tip! Found working one! `SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT asso.id_tag) as cnt FROM crm_task t LEFT JOIN crm_task_tagtogroup asso ON (asso.id_task = t.id_task AND asso.id_tag IN (1, 6) ) GROUP BY t.id_task HAVING cnt = 2`
Does not work without `asso.id_task = t.id_task`